# Did El Capitan DP8 Break Connections to LocalHost in MAMP PRO 3.4?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, macos, apache, localhost

Here's the situation. This morning after installing `El Capitan DP8`, I noticed that I was no longer able to connect to my `WordPress blog`. Firefox's status bar just says `connecting`, but it never connects. As a first recourse, I manually reinstalled `WP 4.3`, and set overall `folder/file permissions` in my WP directory to 777 as a test. Reinstallation and permissions change didn't help.

However, then I discovered that neither could I connect to any of the domains which I host with `MAMP PRO`. So my next step was to reinstall `MAMP PRO 3.4`, replacing the `db` and `htdocs` folders with my original ones. Still no success.

Mind you, I have no problem connecting to external websites via Firefox. It is just my local domains that don't work. Firefox just says "connecting", followed by the intended URL.

In addition, I have done the following, although not necessarily in this order:

1. Installed OS X El Capitan DP8 Firmware Update.
2. Installed OS X El Capitan DP8 a second time.
3. Verified that my "hosts" file is in order and not corrupted via nano.
4. Used "Sequel Pro" to check, and if necessary, repair all of the tables in my WordPress database. None required repair, and I can see all of the data in the tables going back four years.
5. Restarted my cable modem and Apple Airport Extreme.
6. Verified my LAN settings via Airport Utility.
7. Verified that the folder paths to my various domains are still correct in MAMP PRO.

Despite doing all of the above -- which included a few machine restarts -- I am still unable to connect to my local domains.

MAMP PRO starts up just fine, and all of my settings in MAMP PRO look fine. My ports are set to the default 80, 443 and 3306, as they have always been. I see all of my domains listed on the "Hosts" tab. My Apache and mySQL users are set to the suggested ones.

At this point, I am at a loss regarding what to do. Has anyone else encountered this? Do you have any possible solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem, but my MAMP won't even start up. The Start Servers button just gets a little spinner for a few seconds, then it's gone and only MySQL Server starts up. Can't get Apache running.

Comment: @Ace Going by the description of your problem, I don't believe that you're experiencing the same thing that I did. My problem had nothing to do with the Apache and mySQL servers not starting up. In my case, they started up just fine. What I experienced was strictly a connection issue AFTER the servers started up. As it turns out, and as I explain in this thread -- https://forums.obdev.at/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10059&sid=52f6725d901ea9dd6f50ac63e4df2ab7 -- the culprit in my case was a conflict between El Capitan & Little Snitch. It has since been fixed. There was never anything wrong with MAMP PRO

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this and had the exact my.cnf and renamed the latest version to something like my-old.cnf, restarted MAMP Pro and it worked.

Hope that helps others.